# Error Getting Key From Blob_Info on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        reseller_id = self.request.get('reseller_id')
        upload_files = self.request.get('logo_img')
        if upload_files:
            blob_info = upload_files[0]
            key = blob_info.key()
```

I get an error at the line

```
key = blob_info.key()
```

error:

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'key
```

The thing is the file uploads correctly and I can see it in the GAE blob viewer.  I copied this code from the Upload example here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App

I am at a loss as to why I am not getting the key value by using blob_info.key()  any pointers will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the example they do:

```
upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
```

In your example upload_files is the value the user set for the logo_img field, which is a string.

I imagine the logo_img field is the file the user is uploading , so you would need to do instead

```
upload_files = self.get_uploads('logo_img')
```